# How to load model data in application template for authenticated users

Tags: ember.js

I followed ESA dummy app example steps to implement implicit grant authentication. It works fine, but I wonder how to proceed in the below situation:
- usually we define navbar, in the application template
- `application.js` route is defined like [that](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/routes/application.js)
- I need to load all the shops in a drop-down list in the navbar of `application` template only if a user us authenticated.
- in `application.hbs` template I defined the `select` list as follows:

```
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <select>
            {{#each model as |shop|}}
              <option value={{shop.id}}>{{shop.shopName}}</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </li>
      {{/if}}
```

- if I add a model hook to the `application.js` router:

  ```
  model() {
      if (this.get("session.isAuthenticated")) {
        return this.store.findAll('shop');
      }
    },
  ```

it works, but I have to refresh the page to have the drop-down list populated. It seems like, my `model` hook is ignored because of `before_model` hook that authenticates a User:

```
beforeModel() {
  return this._loadCurrentUser();
}
```

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: beforeModel wouldn't cancel a model hook unless you explicitly abort the transition (https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Route/methods/model?anchor=beforeModel). Are you hitting your model function with a `debugger;`?

Comment: The problem is that `application.js` route is defined as non-authenticated: `export default Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {...}` compared to others routes which are protected, like `dashboard.js` route for example: `export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {...}`. The solution I came to for the moment is to move the select-box to `dashboard.hbs` template and load shops in `model` hooks in the `dashboard.js` route.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `ember-simple-auth`, you could add `sessionAuthenticated` method to application route and refresh the route:

```
sessionAuthenticated() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.refresh();
}
```